# My Discord bot is not responding to messages/not even outputting to terminal?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Trying to make a sorta complicated bot, but before i get started on writing the other code I wanted to just make sure that the bot worked in Discord, and was up and running and responding to a basic command - Send the message "Hello" when someone used the command "!hello".

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
TOKEN = "TOKEN"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot connected as {bot.user}')


@bot.command(name='hello')
async def dosomething(ctx):
    print(f'Hello command made')
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

  bot.run(TOKEN)
```

the on_ready function does work, it outputs the name of the bot whenever it connects, but trying to get it to respond to a simple !hello command does nothing, it doesnt message in the channel and it doesn't print to console. Here's my permissions for the bot as well from Discord Developer Portal - https://i.stack.imgur.com/abkjP.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this at the line above `commands.Bot`

```py
intents.message_content = True
```

Comment: that worked perfectly thank you! Always one line away from functional haha

Comment: glad to help u :)